# How to correctly use PowerBI's REST API?

Tags: python, powerbi

I have been working on using the powerbi REST API and I haven't been able to properly make use of it. I made use of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/walkthrough-push-data) and I was able to register an app and get as far as getting an access token, but still I get 401 statuses on my requests.

My major points of confusion are with regards to the app registration:
1) I am trying to read and write data from a python script. Is this a Native-App or a Web Side Server?

2) What is the meaning of the redirect and home urls on the app registration page? I am currently using my localhost:5000 with different /paths. Could this be the source of the issue?

3) My research indicates that there should be some sort of login interaction. I don't have one, is this an indication that something isn't being done properly?

My code is as follows:

```
import adal
import requests

AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my_company}.onmicrosoft.com'
RESOURCE = 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'
CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

def make_headers(access_token):
    return {
      'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(access_token)
    }

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(RESOURCE, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)

access_token = token['accessToken']
headers = make_headers(access_token)
url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets"
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

As I said above this works to give me an access token though a get a status 401 response on the request and there is no sign in prompt.
Any help/guidance would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) In your case you should register a Native app.

2) Native apps has only Redirect URI. Redirect URI gives AAD more details about the specific application it authenticates. For Native apps you should set it to https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf.

3) It's hard to say why you are getting Unauthorized response. Check what rights you gave to your application - does it has rights to read or write all datasets? Try to decode the access token at https://jwt.io and look at scp -  does it contain "Dataset.Read.All" or "Dataset.ReadWrite.All"?